# Does following funtion exists?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exists  two real valued functions $f$ and  $g$ on $R$ such that  $f \circ g  = x^{2018}$ and $ g\circ f  = x^{2019}$ ?

My attempt : since  $g \circ f $ is bijective thus 
$f$ is one one and $g$ is onto.
Now  $f \circ g(-x) = f \circ g(x) $ imply $ g(-x) = g(x) $ (because $ f $ is one one) thus g is even function. 
Now i dont know how to proceed from here any hint will be helpfull for me....
(I know no such map exists as answer)

Answer (score 0):

$$g(f(x))=\ x^{2019}$$ 
$$=> f(g(f(x)))=f(\ x^{2019})$$
$$=> (f(x))^{2018}=f(x^{2019})$$ (by associativity of function composition)

there exist no such f and g because$ f(1)=1, f(-1)=1 => g(1)=1$  and $ g({(-1)}^{2018})=-1$

contradiction hence proved

well one may argue f(1)=0

in that case consider $f(0),f(1),f(-1) $will have either 1 or 0 value and by pigeon hole principle two of them will have atleast same value hence we are done

Comment: What if $f(1) = 0$?

Comment: hmm you are correct

Comment: consider then f(0),f(-1),f(1) they can be 0 or 1

Comment: by pigeon hole principle atleast two of them will have same value so we are done